# Smartgwt font size in text input using css

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

When I put this in my css file:

`label, input
{
  font-size: 18px;
}`

Text labels show up with font size 18, but text boxes aren't affected.
Also, when looking at the generated html code in the browser (Inspect element, using Chrome), I'm seeing that the input box has a set height.

So the question is, can I control the size of the text box and the size of the font inside the text box using just css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the !important declaration your css would take precedence on the smartgwt css declaration.
I've just tried and it works.

```
    label, input {
        font-size: 18px !important;
    }
```

Comment: Is this the official (I would say "documented", but there is no documentation on this) way to do this?